# NGRX Action strange behavior

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using NGRX state management for an Angular app and I'm noticing some strange behavior which is becoming tricky to pinpoint the source. Anyone have any ideas why a dispatched action that is not setup to any reducer functions still ends up reducing my state?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And elaborate what do you mean by strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `default` case inside your reducer's `switch` statement?
If so, could it be that you're modifying state here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I basically had to deep copy the action payload in the reducer before setting it as a state property. Otherwise the state property had the same references and it was automatically updating the state. This may be because on this project it was decided to not fully abide by the NGRX pattern rules in some cases but while still utilizing the NGRX store.